# Many mistakes Attempt to read from field 'android.os.Handler android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHandler' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-fabric

I get hundreds of errors of this kind, my opinion is that this is either google components or the fabric that I recently connected
foto crash [Crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBrvI.png).
I have no "**[TextureView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxLso.png)**" in the code anywhere even close, who gives such an error?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.Handler android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHandler' on a null object reference
       at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:387)
       at android.view.TextureView.draw(TextureView.java:339)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16196)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17217)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16196)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17217)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:757)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16196)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2844)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2652)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2259)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1298)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:876)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:688)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:623)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:862)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```